# How to delete row in the big database after store new database (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server database which store a row per second, after 1 month, 2 month while database is very big over 1 million rows. I want to know how to backup or delete old rows after database is automatically updated to new database.

Comment: Well you could periodically archive your data, moving to another table or maybe even another database.

Comment: do you have timestamps on all the records, so you can select which ones to delete?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a kind of "generic code" I build some years ago for the Archives and it works quite well. I have adapted for you a little bit.
It assumes you have a field called DateRecord with the date that the record was added or modified last. Also, you have ProdDB and ArchiveDB and one table with same structure in ProdDB than in ArchiveDB except the ID in the ArchiveDB cannot be IDENTITY but can have a UNIQUE index:

```
-- Deletes from the Archive if older than one year
 DELETE FROM ArchiveDB.dbo.YourTable
 WHERE DateDiff(d, DateRecord, GetDate()) > 365 

-- Insert into the ArchiveDB table if older than 30 days (set your request here)
 INSERT INTO ArchiveDB.dbo.YourTable
     SELECT * FROM ProdDB.dbo.YourTable SRC 
     WHERE DateRecord < DATEADD(d, -30, GETDATE())
       AND NOT EXISTS ( 
           SELECT 1 FROM ArchiveDB.dbo.YourTable DST 
           WHERE    SRC.[ID] = DST.[ID]     )

-- Delete from ProdDB if older than 30 days and has been moved to the ArchiveDB
 DELETE FROM ProdDB.dbo.YourTable 
 WHERE DateRecord < DATEADD(d, -30, GETDATE())
   AND EXISTS ( 
       SELECT 1 FROM ArchiveDB.dbo.YourTable DST 
       WHERE        [ID] = DST.[ID]     )
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that useful. I will try.

Comment: Great !!! If it works, please, vote me up and set as the correct response. For me it is working fine in a production environment for several tables with several millions of records in total.

Comment: Yes, it's operate. You can see below.

Answer (score 0):

I is consult @Angel M.'s code and i have result that operated. Thanks Angel

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE @Ngayhientai Datetime = GETDATE();
 DECLARE @ngayquakhu Datetime;
 DECLARE @datrungay Datetime;
 DECLARE @Daylakieuso int;
 DECLARE @lastyear int;


  SELECT TOP(1) @ngayquakhu = daylabientable.DateTime
 FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].TableModbus daylabientable;

 SELECT @Daylakieuso = DATEDIFF(d,@ngayquakhu,@Ngayhientai)
 FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[TableModbus];

 IF @Daylakieuso>1
 INSERT INTO [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[SaoluuTable]([STT],[RegisterModbus],[DateTime])
 SELECT [STT],[RegisterModbus],[DateTime]
 FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[TableModbus] nguondulieu
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[SaoluuTable] laylinkgoc
  WHERE laylinkgoc.DateTime = nguondulieu.DateTime);

 SELECT TOP(1) @datrungay = honmotthang.DateTime
 FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[SaoluuTable] honmotthang;

 SELECT @lastyear = DATEDIFF(d,@datrungay,@Ngayhientai)
 FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[TableModbus];

 IF @lastyear=365
 INSERT INTO  [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[Dulieuhon1nam]([STT],[RegisterModbus],[DateTime]) 
  SELECT [STT],[RegisterModbus],[DateTime]
  FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[SaoluuTable] thoidinhe
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[SaoluuTable] chisokhac
  WHERE chisokhac.DateTime = thoidinhe.DateTime);
 IF @lastyear>365
 DELETE FROM [DatabaseMobus].[dbo].[SaoluuTable];
```

END